# An error was encountered with the requested page AWS User Pool with Swift

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-amplify, sign-in-with-apple

I'm trying to use AWS Cognite User Pool to login with AppleId for iOS application. We couldn't use federated identity, I must use User Pool. While login User Pool, I use hosted UI in iOS application.  I had set up service configuration on Aws and iOS application seen below. When I tried to login User Pool, I take a 'An error was encountered with the requested page ' error in WebView.

```
let hostedUIOptions = HostedUIOptions(identityProvider: "SignInWithApple")

    AWSMobileClient.default().showSignIn(navigationController: self.navigationController!, hostedUIOptions: hostedUIOptions) { (userState, error) in
        if let error = error as? AWSMobileClientError {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        if let userState = userState {
            print("Status: \(userState.rawValue)")
        }
    }
```

AWSConfiguration.json

```
{
"IdentityManager": {
    "Default": {}
},

"CognitoUserPool": {
    "Default": {
        "PoolId": "eu-west-1_rsPBto6Jx",
        "AppClientId": "6atv5t6egacicor9cioXXXXXX",
        "AppClientSecret": "171du4k8rf098lmnuvhm2h3o1umqcdfnngcj84tc304moXXXXXXXX",
        "Region": "us-east-2"
    }
},
"Auth": {
       "Default": {
           "OAuth": {
               "WebDomain": "XXXXX.auth.us-east-2.amazoncognito.com",
               "AppClientId": "6atv5t6egacicor9cioXXXXXX",
               "AppClientSecret": "171du4k8rf098lmnuvhm2h3o1umqcdfnngcj84tc304moXXXXXXXX",
               "SignInRedirectURI": "myapp://",
               "SignOutRedirectURI": "myapp://",
               "Scopes": ["openid", "email","aws.cognito.signin.user.admin","profile","phone"]
           }
       }
   }
```

}

How can I solve this problem?

**Solution**

When I add callback url in consol myapp://sigout, problem was solved.It is my mistake.

Comment: Can you provide some insight into the error code? Is this the only message you receive or could you log the entire error debug description please?

Comment: I didn't take any error in debug consol. 'An error was encountered with the requested page' messages shown in web view

Comment: Ok but could you set a breakpoint where it says `print(error.localizedDescription)` maybe you can see some detailed error information.